# what does linear type mean?

Tags: group-theory, general-topology, topological-groups

What does it mean when we say a topological group $\Gamma$ has linear type?

Is it an algebraic property or a topology property?

I wonder if anyone could give some references.

Comment: You should probably tell us what reference you're looking at; different authors may mean different things. I would _guess_ it means that the group admits a continuous injective homomorphism into $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ for some $n$, but who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer: I found in [*Annals of Mathematics*, vol. 40, no. 3, July, 1939](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1968942) that:

An "Abelian, convex, connected, and sequentially complete Hausdorff group such that it possesses no elements of finite order may be called a linear topological group.

Comment: Thanks, that's a definition I could understand.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the right answer, but maybe it is helpful.

An *algebraic group* is an [algebraic variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety) $G$ together two maps
$$\begin{align}
&\mu: G \times G \to G & &(x,y) \mapsto xy\\
&i: G \to G        & &x \mapsto x^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
which are both morphisms of varieties.

Now if the varieties are *affine*, then we say that $G$ is a *linear* algebraic group.

Now this might not be what you are studying. Even thougth there is an underlying topology (the Zariski topology) on $G$, it [doesn't mean that the group is a topological group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Algebraic_group_not_implies_topological_group).